# How to show, hidden QGraphicsItem in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am having QGraphicsView, which has multiple QGraphicsItem's. In QGraphicsItem's, I am having few rectangles and some polylines. Polylines are attached to rectangles.
I have a feature Hide Rectangle in which I manually select a few rectangles from view and then on the right mouse button, there is an option like Hide Rectangles which calls the function HideSelectedRectangles() which hides the selected rectangles.

Its code is :

myClass.h

```
 VertexDescriptor vPtr;
```

myClass.cpp

```
     void myClass::HideSelectedRectangles()
        {
            foreach(QGraphicsItem* currentItem, scene->selectedItems())
            {
                guiSchematicRect* rItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<guiSchematicRect*>(currentItem);
                if(rItem)
               {
                   vPtr = rItem->getPtr();
                   // iterating over the boost graph using vPtr and making its adjacent vertices         
    //as _isVisisble = false like (*bGraph)[vPtr]._isVisible = false;     
   //(Here paint() gets called automatically and hides the rectangle.)
               }
            }
       }
```

myRect.cpp

```
void guiSchematicRect::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
   auto copied_option = *option;
copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
auto selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
QGraphicsRectItem::paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);

if(selected)
{
    painter->save();
    painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::SolidLine));
    painter->drawPath(shape());
    painter->restore();
}
   vRectPtr = this->getBoostPtr();
   if((*bGraph)[vRectPtr]._isVisible == false)
        this->hide();
    else
        this->show();
}
```

Once Rectangles get hidden, there is a Refresh button that expects to bring back all the hidden objects.

```
   void myClass::Refresh()
    {
       // iterating over the boost graph using vPtr and making its adjacent vertices         
//as _isVisisble = true like (*bGraph)[vPtr]._isVisible = true;      
//(Here paint() does not get called automatically to unhide rectangle.)
    }
```

Comment: `hiddenRectangles` is locally scoped in `myClass::HideSelectedRectangles`.

Comment: @G.M. I have declared `hiddenRectangles` in `myClass.h` but still problem persist.

Comment: @tushar So you deleted it from `HideSelectedRectangles()`, right? I am just double checking...

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile Yes. I changed my code.

Comment: Have you checked that the item pointers are correct in the vector when you call `Refresh()`? So that for example when you hidden 4 rectangles, the `for` cycle loops  four times?

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile Yes. I checked that. I printed it's size and it's value in for loop. It is showing correct.

Comment: Seems really strange. Aren't these child items of some other item which got hidden? Or aren't they hidden behind some other item?

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile @G.M.   I did not earlier the real code as it is confusing because it involes `boost-graph`. But now showing. I try to explain what I am doing here. Every `QgraphicsItem` I am considering a node and storing boost-graph pointer on it. Boost graph has a one property _isVisible which can be true or false.  So when I select any item to hide, I try to get stored boost-graph pointer from it, iterate over it and its every adjacent node I make invisible using `_isVisible` flag. Now paint() gets called for every object, I again get pointer from it ( this->getBoostPtr)

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile @G.M.  checks condition and hides the item. It works perfectly.  But problem comes when I want to unhide the hidden items. I agian iterate over graph, make every adjacent node as _isVisible = true. And here I expect that `paint()` should get called and and `this->show()` should get execute. But it is not happening.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile @G.M. I checked every nodes visibility. It is showing _isVisible = true but for that it's `paint()` is not getting called.  While hidding `paint()` gets called but while unhidding `paint()` does not get called. So I thought, I should not use `this->show()` so to check that, I created simple example and use `this->show()` But from your reply it seems that `this->show()` is correct.

Comment: Why are you calling `show`/`hide` from within the `paint` method?  That makes no sense to me.  Also, that's the *only* thing you do within `paint`: where do you actually perform the painting operation?

Comment: @G.M. I have updated my `paint()` .  Actually what I am thinking that, whenever I will do any updates on any `QGraphicsItem` that item's `paint()` gets called.  And how will I get that item ? Through `this`. So I am getting stored pointer of that item through `this->getBoostPtr()` then checking it's visibility. If it is `true` then simply show that item otherwise dont show.  Am I right in thinking ? Actually I am confused how `paint()` gets called. Can you tell me ?

Comment: Next time, please add UPDATEs to you original question. If you are editing and changing existing text, the answers or comments here do not make any sense now.